# HTML Table Custom Cell Widths

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and this site in general, so I don't know how best to ask my question, but here it goes. I am working on a school project where I'm supposed to make a table which features a bunch of HTML related elements in each of the cells (radio buttons, checkboxes, different font types, etc.), and at the bottom of this table in the last row, I am asked to put there buttons and make each button stretch to cover 1/3 of the entire table width. My table has 5 columns in total, so simply writing the three buttons in on one row leaves 2 empty column spaces at the end. I've tried googling for answers online, but not a single forum or website I've come across has anything related to my problem, so coming here is kind of my last resort. I've tried putting width="33%" directly into the  element, but it just makes the entire column take up 33% of the entire page, which is not what I want. Hopefully someone knows what to do, because I'm at a total loss.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><i><p>It's February<br>
  There is a Christmas tree<br>
  in the field across the way;<br>
  the strength of shoulders<br>
  on the back of the chair<br>
  your yesterday's shirt<br>
  in the corner of my bedroom,<br>
  new and fresh<br>
  it was not there before.<br>
  and in the dim light<br>
  my old mirror shows my face young.</p></i></td>

        <td><input type="checkbox">Brandon<br>
          <input type="checkbox">George<br>
          <input type="checkbox">Sam<br>
          <input type="checkbox">Emily<br>
          <input type="checkbox">Sarah<br></td>

        <td><input type="radio" name="name1">Harry<br>
          <input type="radio" name="name1">Veronica<br>
          <input type="radio" name="name1">Garry<br>
          <input type="radio" name="name1">John<br>
          <input type="radio" name="name1">Ivan<br></td>

        <td colspan="2"><img src="mount fuji.jpg" height="200" width="200"><br>
          <p style="text-align:center">Mount Fuji</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="font-size:60%">The book I am currently reading<br> is George Orwell's "1984". It's a<br> postapocalyptic story about a world<br> where after a great war took place<br> a faction named "The Party" took over<br> and began to impose their tyranical<br> views upon
          its subjects. It follows<br> a middle-aged man named Winston as<br> he seeks to find out the truth about<br> "The Party" and if he can even escape<br> their evil grasp.</td>

        <td colspan="2"><img src="toronto.jpg" height="100" width="200"></td>

        <td style="text-align:center">John, Smith</td>

        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="hawes.jpg" height="100" width="200"></td>

        <td>The Wizard of OZ</td>

        <td>
          <select name="numbers">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <input type="hidden" name="Brandon K" value="214790158">

      <tr align="center">
        <td align="center"><button type="button">Button1</button></td>
        <td align="center"><button type="button">Button2</button></td>
        <td align="center"><button type="button">Button3</button></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

It took me a while, but I finally learned how to post the code.

[Here's what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHOoZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

colspan is the attribute you are looking for. It make one cell take up multiple columns.

```
<td colspan="3">
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>single</td>
    <td>single</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">double</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But what if let's say in the second row, you also had two cells, and you wanted one cell to take up 70% of the row space and the other to take up the other 30%? And I don't mean 70% of the entire screen, just 70% of the width of the table. Thank you though.

Comment: The point of a table is to have all the columns and rows line up, it is for displaying tabular data, if you have requirements that are not tabular then build your own grid instead of using a table.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want. On `style="width:XX"` inside the div of the body you set how much width of each div. For some reason, the 2 Divs can occupy 99% in total.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body { margin:0; /* This is used to reset any browser-default margins */ }

div.main{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}
div.border{
    border-width:0.1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
div.left{
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}
div.right{
float:left;

overflow:hidden;
}
#left{

}
#right{

} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">

<div class="border left" style="width:69%">almost 70%, in fact is 69%</div>
<div class="border right" style="width:30%">30%</div>
<div class="border left" style="width:30%">30%</div>
<div class="border right" style="width:69%">almost 70%, in fact is 69%</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```